# Find out when a user was created and display varied content depending on time since creation

Tags: users

I am looking to display different content after a user registers.  Is there a way to find out the registration date and then if it's been 1 day display one thing, but if it's been 2 days display something else?

Something like this, but based on the registration date and not a post entry date:

```
<?php if (strtotime($post->post_date) > strtotime('-30 days')): ?>
   //Text for posts created in the last 30 days
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can!

```
<?php 
get_currentuserinfo(); 
$user_data = get_userdata($user_ID);
$registered_date = $user_data->user_registered;
if (strtotime($registered_date) > strtotime('-30 days')){
   //Text for users registered in the last 30 days
}
?>
```

hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the help but I am getting this error now: 
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: my bad, i updated the code, its $user_data->user_registered instead of $user_data['user_registered'],
if not then paste your code here so we could see

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I have simply pasted this code into a wordpress template, so no additional code to share and I am now getting this error:Parse error: syntax error, unexpected

Comment: ok weird, try the posted answer now and id not please post your code

Comment: Ok, figured it out.  I edited the code above.  It was missing a ending ) after $registered_date

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have tested this and it works perfectly!

Comment: i see that and updated the code 
glad to help , remember to check as answered if this answere your question.

Answer (score 2):

The above code is now deprecated.

```
    <?php  
$user_data = get_userdata(get_current_user_id());
$registered_date = $user_data->user_registered;
if (strtotime($registered_date) > strtotime('-30 days')){
   //Text for users registered in the last 30 days
}
?>
```